# How to get multifield(subfields value) in rules Drupal 7

Tags: 7, rules

i use the [multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) module with multifield table display in my entityform.

So, in my entityform i have one multifield type with 5 subfields.

How can i get subfield value in Rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to "drill down" your entity and find the subfields. This is [a great tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/data-types-and-data-selection?p=1157) on how to drill down your data in rules. If it's not available, you can "Fetch an entity by id" into rules (under actions) and then it will be available.